# How to use Mixin and ActiveRecord:Base together

Tags: ruby-on-rails, database, oop, mixins

Consider this simple application in RUby on Rails:

Student & Teacher extends Person.
Person has 2 properties,  name & age.
Student has 1 extra property, grade.
Teacher has 1 extra property, salary.

I want to store the student & teacher information in separate db tables. I want to take advantage of RoR's utility class `ActiveRecord:Base` to retrive data for these models. Because `Person` is not expected to be instantiated, I can mix it with `Student` & `Teacher` as follows:

```
class Student < ActiveRecord:Base
include Person
end

module Person
end
```

Question:

1. Is this the correct way of implementation?
2. How to implement this without creating a databse table called `persons`? I only want to generate 2 tables, namely `students` and `teachers`, and both should have the 3 properties mentioned above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Person does not have to be a model - it can be a library/module (which you then mixin as per your example). You'd keep that in RAILS_ROOT/lib.
Your Student and Teacher classes can be models (which use AR::Base), and the person can just be a bunch of common methods used by both.

Alternatively, if your child class is far more complicated - look into "Single table inheritance" - the description of which is beyond the scope of this answer... but you can google for it.

Comment: This will only work if you add `name` and `age` fields to both `student` and `teacher` tables.

Comment: Yes - you do need to add the same columns to both. Just do that in the migration.

Comment: Would that not defeat the purpose of inheriting the columns from "Person"?

Comment: Ah - I'd assumed you actually had something more substantial than just two columns. Two columns is simple enough that duplication is quicker to write, cleaner and simpler to understand and thus much easier to maintain in the long-run.

Comment: Yes. In my real application, both the child classes have almost all the fields same. But their concerns are different and thus need to be saved differently. Also, adding the fields again means twice the maintainance. Everytime I need to make a change in one, I have to update both classes too.

Comment: yeah - that's definitely more of a pain. Ok - change of plan. Have you looked into single table inheritance? (google it for more).

Comment: Oh crap.. For some reason I did not get update for the last comment and the edit in your answer. And I went ahead with the mixin solution.  STI seems a way better fit to my question. Oh well, will refactor all my code some day! Thanks!